# Stop X window manger

Tags: unity, ubuntu-gnome, window-manager

I have standard Ubuntu 20.04 installation with default desktop manager. I would like to stop X windows. What command I should run in order to achieve that?

Comment: What is a standard install. You give no version number  or any details. Server desktop.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04